# Jquery-Mobile: validation

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile concept. The validation in the jquery mobile is similar to jquery or not. Please give me the easy tutorials links to understand the validations.

thanks

Comment: Why this post is closed? This post is based on real practical problem and very useful to many developers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a normal JQuery validation plugin - [here's an example](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-form-validation.html) of JQM validation done using such a plugin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark as Answer for the other members! 10x